# Is there any way to get globalCompositeOperation copy work like it does in Chrome, but in Firefox/Opera?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

Trying to free-hand draw on a canvas without having opacity 1, however it turns out like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry7vv.png

Setting globalCompositeOperation to copy solves it, however in Firefox/Opera copy clears the entire canvas before drawing, unlike how it does it in Chrome. I know another solution is to redraw all the lines as one before applying stroke every time you draw, however it's quite the performance hit just to get opacity to work.

Comment: You most likely don't need to change the globalCompositeOperation. If you're trying to set opacity, this is normally done with setting ctx.fillStyle or ctx.strokeStyle to an rgba value like: rgba(0,0,0,0.5). You set this before you call ctx.fill() or ctx.stroke(). Similarly, if you want to set a particular opacity for many things try setting [globalAlpha](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-2dcontext-20100624/#dom-context-2d-globalalpha).

Comment: You and @KerryLiu are both on the right track.  Combine your lines into 1 beginPath.  Keep in mind that with opacity<1.00 the drawings are cumulative--that's why you see "dots" in your stroke.  Combining your line segments into 1 path eliminates the "dots".  And Kerry Liu is correct that you (probably) don't need globalCompositeOperation and you can set a strokeStyle with alpha<1.00 to achieve your effect--again combining your strokes into 1 path to avoid "dots".